# How to tell Fixit linter to ignore a single file within a directory of interest?

Tags: python, lint

This has to have a simple answer but I couldn't find it on the documentation.

Fixit is a Python Lint Framework based on LibCST.
https://pypi.org/project/fixit/

In my project there exists a file I wish fixit to ignore.
How can I tell instagram's fixit to ignore a file or a directory?

Fixit's documentation mentions the use of `lint-ignore` which does not work. The `--use-ignore-comments` flag (also mentioned on the same page) seem to be deprecated, it's not recognised by the CLI interface.

```
fixit: error: unrecognized arguments: --use-ignore-comments
```

How can one simply tell fixit to ignore a single file?